# How to manually set Fragment in GridActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Given a GridActivity (own naming) extending an `Activity` to display Fragments of a `GridViewPager`. The Fragments are dynamically created in a GridAdapter (own naming) extending a `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` in its overridden `public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col)` method.

How can I manually have a `Fragment` (e.g. row=2, col=3) displayed in the GridActivity (e.g. upon receiving an `Intent` in a `BroadcastReceiver`)?
I'm looking for something like `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().showFragment(2,3)`.

Comment: provide some code of what you done

Comment: Do you want to scroll to that position or do you want to show the fragment independently from the rest of the other fragments?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I managed to do it by calling the method `setCurrentItem()` on my mGridViewPager object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `GridViewPager`'s `setCurrentItem(row, col)` method.